# Java vs JavaScript give diff result for same equation & input values

Tags: java, javascript

The follwoing equation & values give differnet outputs using Java/Javscript:
Javascript:

```
var dayOfWeek = parseInt((dayOfMonth + 26 * (monthOfYear +1) / 10 + yearOfCentury + yearOfCentury / 4 + century / 4 + 5 * century) % 7);
```

Java:

```
int dayOfWeek = (dayOfMonth + 26 * (monthOfYear +1) / 10 + yearOfCentury + yearOfCentury / 4 + century / 4 + 5 * century) % 7; code here
```

If dayOfMonth =28, monthOfYear =7, yearOfCentury = 9, century=20

Java returns dayOfWeek = 3 (which is correct!)
JS returns dayOfWeek = 4! (odd)

Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because java is performing integer operations, as all variables have type `int`.

This code:

```
int dayOfMonth = 28, monthOfYear = 7, yearOfCentury = 9, century = 20;
int result = (dayOfMonth + 26 * (monthOfYear +1) / 10 + yearOfCentury + yearOfCentury / 4 + century / 4 + 5 * century) % 7;
System.out.println(result);
```

Outputs

```
3
```

**Why?**

Your operation means

```
(28 + 26*(7 + 1)/10 + 9 + 8/4 + 20/4 + 5 * 20) % 7.
```

If your variables are all `int`s, every result will be casted to int, so your expression would become

```
(28 + 20 + 9 + 2 + 5 + 100) % 7 = 164 % 7 = 3
```

`26*(7 + 1)/10` is `20.8`, but it's casted to `int`, so you will lose the decimal part.

But if you change the first two lines to

```
double dayOfMonth = 28, monthOfYear = 7, yearOfCentury = 9, century = 20;
double result = (dayOfMonth + 26 * (monthOfYear +1) / 10 + yearOfCentury + yearOfCentury / 4 + century / 4 + 5 * century) % 7;
```

The output will be

```
4.050000000000011
```

Which is the same output you have with javascript. Then you use the `parseInt` function (which in java is `Integer.parseInt`) so the final result will be `4`

Comment: Cheers, so changed the JS equation and got the correct output: var dayOfWeek = parseInt(parseInt(dayOfMonth + 26 * parseInt(monthOfYear +1) / 10 + yearOfCentury + parseInt(yearOfCentury / 4) + parseInt(century / 4) + parseInt(5 * century)) % 7); . Seems long way to go about to, is there are more effective way then breaking down each part of the expression with parseInt()?

Comment: @dancingbush I don't think there is, because javascript doesn't have types as java, everything is `var`, you can't declare an `int`, so it will treat double, int, etc as a generic number, without caring about integer division. I think you will always have floating point operations (if needed) if you don't use `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Re advice from backslash answer:

var dayOfWeek = parseInt(parseInt(dayOfMonth + 26 * parseInt(monthOfYear +1) / 10 + yearOfCentury + parseInt(yearOfCentury / 4) + parseInt(century / 4) + parseInt(5 * century)) % 7); .